# Can't resize bones that have multiple children

Tags: rigging

From an FBX imported rigged character.

All bones that have multiple children don't want to changes scale, they are so small that they are difficult to select in 3D view.

I tried Ctrl+Alt+S didn't work.

How can I change their size without affecting skin weights? [image]

Comment: It would be nice to post some images to describe your difficulty. Usually the bone object would fit your character mesh and would nv be "too small" that they become difficult to select. If they are much much smaller than your character's mesh something is very wrong with the FBX import. Resizing of bone can be done in "Edit Mode" but not in "Pose Mode". Tho usually you will only want to do the resizing of bone before you weight the mesh, and not after.

Comment: Added an image to show the bones are there just tiny as one of the hash lines.

Answer (score 1):

To make bones more visible in the 3dview without altering there size you can use a mesh object as a [custom shape](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/armatures/visualization.html#shaped-bones), this mesh object can be any size you wish to make it, the initial size of the object will then be linked to the base scale of the bone.

If you have trouble finding bones, the outliner is a great place to find things. You can select an item in the outliner, delete it, rename it... (<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> for context menu) It includes a search box to easily find items by name with search matches highlighted.

The little `+` next to an item will show children or other data like animation and materials, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> on the `+` will expand all sub-items.

[image]